# How to show my current position and region onto my MKMapView with using blue dots ?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am trying to create the dummy map view demo for iOS  and storyboard allowing current user location to be acquired. When it comes to execution, I have to scroll and swipe to find my current location but not being set at the region nearby my current location. What should I implement in order to achieve this for instance using MK Coordinates or MKMap Region? the below is my .m implementation code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_mapView setCenterCoordinate:_mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
    MKAnnotationView *userLocationView = [_mapView viewForAnnotation:_mapView.userLocation];
    [userLocationView.superview bringSubviewToFront:userLocationView];
}
```

Comment: Simplest option is to set userTrackingMode to MKUserTrackingModeFollow.  Otherwise, you can set the map's centerCoordinate in the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method (don't need a CLLocationManager).  Do not try to directly manipulate the annotation view hierarchy (using bringSubviewToFront, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MAPKIT](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html)

First allow your map to show your current location.

```
 _mapView.showsUserLocation   =   YES; // This will show the blue dot on map at your current location.
```

Now Set the Region to zoom on your current location.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude           =      _mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;;
    region.center.longitude          =      _mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;;

    region.span.latitudeDelta        =      0.001;
    region.span.longitudeDelta       =      0.001;

    MKCoordinateRegion scaledRegion  =       [_mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [_mapView setRegion:scaledRegion animated:NO];
```

Make Sure to set the Region after your location is visible over map or your map is completly loaded. You can make use to delegates..

```
- (void)mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView;
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView;
```

If you want to manage the UserLocation by userself..
You can use [**CLLocationManager**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) class Initialize it and Use it's Delegate to get the updates on User's Current location.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager  =           [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy     =           kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
```

// Delegate

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
// Use New Location to show your custom marker or do any thing you want.
}
```

For Debugging in Simulator you set the GPS location
Go to Simulator option **DEBUG-->LOCATION** .. You can add custom location or can chose from the available ones.

Hope this will help you. :)